# Query for dropping value from field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that looks at duty and vat information and does calculation based on the returned value.

The column that tells me the duty rates is in the table formatted as either, for example 3.7% or 8% in both bases I need remove the % from my return value. Otherwise my SUM clasue fails.

I have sorted the problem for the 3.7% example with the follwoing:

```
CASE WHEN CustomsTariff.CommodityCode.StandardDuty = 'Free' THEN '0.0' ELSE SUBSTRING(CustomsTariff.CommodityCode.StandardDuty, 1, 3) END AS DutyRate,
```

This drops the % for any returns where there is decimal palce but I need to add to the CASE to say if the StandardDuty value has no decimal places drop the % character as well without messing up the first statement that looks to the 1st 3 digits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a `replace()` on the `%` character? [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
CASE WHEN CustomsTariff.CommodityCode.StandardDuty = 'Free'
     THEN '0.0' ELSE REPLACE(CustomsTariff.CommodityCode.StandardDuty, N'%', N'')
END AS DutyRate,
```